# Why this.$slots.slotname return undefined even when template is in slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Child Component with named-slots

```
<template>
  <v-menu v-model="menu"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          bottom
          min-width="300"
          offset-y
  >
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn class="p-absolute p-right"
             icon
             style="right: 0;"
             v-bind="attrs"
             v-on="on"
      >
        <v-icon>
          mdi-sort
        </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list dense>

      <slot name="group"
            :groupBy="groupBy"
      />

      <slot name="sort"
            :direction="direction"
            :sortBy="sortBy"
      />
</template>
```

also i have a Parent component which looks like this

```
<template>
    <Child>
        <template #group="{ groupBy }">
                  <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                      {{ $t('group_by') }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item>

                  <v-list-item>
                    <v-autocomplete
                        v-model="groupBy.value"
                        label="Label"
                        dense
                        :items="items"
                    >
                    </v-autocomplete>
                  </v-list-item>
                </template>
        </Child>
</template>
```

When i want to check which of two slots is empty i decided to use
`this.$slots.slot-name` but it returns undefined even when i passed template to `#group`

Comment: Did you check in Child or Parent? `this.$slots` will only work in Child.  Check if there is anything in `this.$slots` in the Child component after passing in `<template #group>` from Parent.  If you can see the slot content in the browser than there should be.

Comment: I check in Child. I know that should, but is it undefined somehow

Comment: Did you miss to close the `v-menu` element? Or did you just forget to copy it here? Are there any errors/warnings  in the console?

Comment: Maybe you can create a stackblitz with your code, or add the full child component here?